# Google Sheets Add Formula Automatically After New Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Zapier to automatically send data to a google sheet and I'm looking for a solution that allows me to automatically add the formula I want in a column when a new row is added.

For example: In column K I'm using this formula:

=VLOOKUP(J2,'List of Employees'!A:B,2,false)

This VLOOKUP function is working properly but only if I double click and expand the formula.
How I can automate this and pass the formula to the next new row created by Zapier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear column K and then enter in K2

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(J2:J), VLOOKUP(J2:J,'List of Employees'!A:B,2,false),))
```

This formula should not be dragged down as it processes all contents of column J and create an output in column K.

I hope that helps?

Comment: Wow! This is the solution! Thanks a lot!